Getting a format error when using with TimeSpan.FromHours()
Debug.LogFormat("The weatherman predicts rain at "
    + TimeSpan.FromHours(startTime)
    + " for "
    + TimeSpan.FromMinutes((timePeriod / 60)).ToString("mm")
    + " minutes");

Could someone tell me the correct format to get just the hours and minutes.
Thanks in advance.
I get the correct format for the minutes but I get an error about wrong formating when I use the following.
TimeSpan.FromHours(startTime).ToString("hh:mm")

The full ERROR looks like this...
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized (System.TimeSpan value, System.ReadOnlySpan1[T] format, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, System.Text.StringBuilder result) (at <8ce0bd04a7a04b4b9395538239d3fdd8>:0) System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatToBuilder (System.TimeSpan value, System.ReadOnlySpan1[T] format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider) (at <8ce0bd04a7a04b4b9395538239d3fdd8>:0)
System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.Format (System.TimeSpan value, System.String format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider) (at <8ce0bd04a7a04b4b9395538239d3fdd8>:0)
System.TimeSpan.ToString (System.String format) (at <8ce0bd04a7a04b4b9395538239d3fdd8>:0)
Weather.PickRandomStartTime () (at Assets/Project Files/_Scripts/Weather.cs:193)
Weather.Update () (at Assets/Project Files/_Scripts/Weather.cs:133)

What is your expected result? 24 hours-based? If yes, it should be "HH", "hh" is for 12 hours-based. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

what type is startTime? FromHours converts a number (double) of hours into TimeSpan

From the docs you can see that any other character in the format string must be escaped with a leading \.
So your code should look like this:
TimeSpan.FromHours(startTime).ToString("hh\\:mm")

Also, as a note, when you create a TimeSpan you don't to consider how it will be formatted - it just stores the time, and not the format. So your second time span can be created like this:
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timePeriod).ToString("mm")


Thanks that was what I needed, I did try TimeSpan.FromHours(startTime).Hours + ":" + TimeSpan.FromHours(startTime).Minutes that gave me the corrct format but yours is really what I was looking for.

If this was the correct answer don't forget to accept it.

regarding TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timePeriod) .. no, this might behave different due to integer division OP was using .. maybe that was intentional to get rid of any decimals and just use full minutes ;)

@derHugo technically that is done already by formatting to seconds,  which is why I pointed this out, but you are probably right.

@EfraimNewman ha I noted until now that this is actually only used to print out the time and not actually using the timespan .. so yes doesn't matter at all, sorry ^^ just using float/int directly without any timespan might even be way more efficient in that case
